# Show that a ring $R$ is a division ring if and only if, for each nonzero $a\in R$, there is a unique element $b\in R$ such that $aba = a$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Show that a ring $R$ is a division ring if and only if, for each nonzero   $a\in R$, there is a unique element $b\in R$ such that $aba = a$.

$\Rightarrow$ Assume $R$ is a division ring. Let $a\in R$. So there exists $a^{-1}$ such that $aa^{-1}=1=a^{-1}a$. So $aa^{-1}=a^{-1}a$.

Now I am not sure to find a $b$ such that $aba=a$?

$\Leftarrow$ Assume $aba=a$ for nonzero $a\in R$. Let $r\in R$ such that $ra=1$. Then $a=aba=a(ra)=(ar)a$ so $ar=1$. Therefore $r$ is the inverse of $a$ and so $a$ is a unit and $R$ is a division ring.

This hinges on the fact that $ra=1$, is that something I can say?

Comment: this was totally in my homework last year, let me see if I an remember

Comment: your solution has some flaws, like for example, why does such an $r$ exist?

Comment: For the forward direction, we have $aa^{-1}a = a$, so let $b = a^{-1}$.

Comment: oh... forward was obvious. And yes I am not sure how to produce such an $r$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $R$ is a division ring. Let $a$ be a non trivial element of $a$, there exists $b$ such that $ab=ba=1$. $aba=(ab)a=1$. Let $c$ such that $aca=a, b(aca)=(ba)(ca)=ba=ca=1$. This implies that $(ca)b=c(ab)=c=b$. So $c$ is unique.

On the other hand, suppose there exists a unique $b$ such that $aba=a$.  We have $aba-a=(ab-1)a=0$, thus $a(b+ab-1)a=aba+a(ab-1)a=aba=a$, since $b$ is unique $b=b+ab-1$, thus $ab=1$. Similar argument shows $ba=1$.

Answer (score 2):

For the return implication:

Suppose there are $r_1\ne r_2$ so that $ar_1=ar_2$, then $a(r_1-r_2)=0$, setting $x=(r_1-r_2)$ we have $(a(b+x))a=(ab)a$. This contradicts the uniqueness of $b$. This proves we can cancel $a$ on the left.

Analogously we can prove we can cancel $a$ on the right.

Using left cancelability:

$a(ba)=a1\implies ba=1$

Using right cancelability:

$(ab)a=1a\implies ab=1$.